# 'Kids' vs 'the kids'

Tags: articles, formal-language, ielts

I'm preparing for academic IELTS by writing some essays and then correcting those using a grammar correction app.

In the following sentence,

> Therefore, despite kids tend to form unfriendly societies, it is
> necessary to gain this experience since it provides an opportunity to
> interact with people of the same age.

The app suggests using 'the kids' rather than just 'kids'. Considering the fact that I'm talking about kids in general as opposed to a specific group of kids, why is this so?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think that there is a grammar issue here far more important than the distinction of "the kids" and "kids".

- "Despite" is a preposition, which means you can not use it as a conjunction such as -although, ever though, but- just as in your sentence. So, the combination you should have used is "Despite+noun".
- Despite kids who tend to..
- Despite kids tending to...

When it comes to "kids" or "the kids", I'd prefer "children" to "kids" in a formal text without "the".